# daply: Correct results, but confusing structure

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data.frame `mydf`, that contains data from 27 subjects. There are two predictors, `congruent` (2 levels) and `offset` (5 levels), so overall there are 10 conditions. Each of the 27 subjects was tested 20 times under each condition, resulting in a total of 10*27*20 = 5400 observations. `RT` is the response variable. The structure looks like this:

```
> str(mydf)
'data.frame':   5400 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ subject  : Factor w/ 27 levels "1","2","3","5",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ congruent: logi  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE ...
 $ offset   : Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "1"<"2"<"3"<"4"<..: 5 5 1 2 5 5 2 2 3 5 ...
 $ RT       : int  330 343 457 436 302 311 595 330 338 374 ...
```

I've used `daply()` to calculate the `mean` RT of each subject in each of the 10 conditions:

```
myarray <- daply(mydf, .(subject, congruent, offset), summarize, mean = mean(RT))
```

The result looks just the way I wanted, i.e. a 3d-array; so to speak 5 tables (one for each `offset` condition) that show the mean of each subject in the `congruent=FALSE` vs. the `congruent=TRUE` condition.

However if I check the structure of `myarray`, I get a confusing output:

```
List of 270
 $ : num 417
 $ : num 393
 $ : num 364
 $ : num 399
 $ : num 374
 ... 
 # and so on
 ...
 [list output truncated]
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:3] 27 2 5
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..$ subject  : chr [1:27] "1" "2" "3" "5" ...
  ..$ congruent: chr [1:2] "FALSE" "TRUE"
  ..$ offset   : chr [1:5] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

This looks totally different from the structure of the prototypical `ozone` array from the `plyr` package, even though it's a very similar format (3 dimensions, only numerical values).

I want to compute some further summarizing information on this array, by means of `aaply`. **Precisely, I want to calculate the difference between the congruent and the incongruent means for each subject and offset.**

**However, already the most basic application of** `aaply()` **like** `aaply(myarray,2,mean)` **returns non-sense output:**

```
FALSE  TRUE 
   NA    NA 
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(piece, ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(piece, ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I have no idea, why the `daply()` function returns such weirdly structured output and thereby prevents any further use of `aaply`. Any kind of help is kindly appreciated, I frankly admit that I have hardly any experience with the `plyr` package.

Comment: It's hard to say for sure without your actual data to play with, but none of what you describe would make me think to use either `daply` or `aaply` at all. I feel like all of this can be done using just `ddply` (and possible `dlply` and `dcast` depending on how you want things to look at the end).

Comment: `summarise` returns a data frame, which you're now trying to sandwhich into an array. You probably are better off not using an array, but if you must, use `daply(mydf, .(subject, congruent, offset), function(df) mean(df$RT))`

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't included your data it's hard to know for sure, but I tried to make a dummy set off your `str()`. You can do what you want (I'm guessing) with two uses of `ddply`. First the means, then the difference of the means.

```
#Make dummy data
mydf <- data.frame(subject = rep(1:5, each = 150), 
  congruent = rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), each = 75), 
  offset = rep(1:5, each = 15), RT = sample(300:500, 750, replace = T))

#Make means
mydf.mean <- ddply(mydf, .(subject, congruent, offset), summarise, mean.RT = mean(RT))

#Calculate difference between congruent and incongruent
mydf.diff <- ddply(mydf.mean, .(subject, offset), summarise, diff.mean = diff(mean.RT))
head(mydf.diff)
#   subject offset  diff.mean
# 1       1      1  39.133333
# 2       1      2   9.200000
# 3       1      3  20.933333
# 4       1      4  -1.533333
# 5       1      5 -34.266667
# 6       2      1  -2.800000
```